# split oracle apex export

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to split exported application file into separate files?

For example I exported an application and have `f115.sql` file. It contains all components but in single file. I want to split it into separate files, such as pages, support components etc. How can it be done?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops, I just found apex export splitter. Will look if it what I want http://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/exporting-an-apex-application-via-command-line/